# Changing background color (and other elements) of a ColorDialog

Tags: c#, colordialog

The default BG color of a ColorDialog is bland and doesn't fit with a dark themed application. Unfortunately the control doesn't come with any BackColor or ForeColor options to directly edit.

How can I go about changing the form's back colors? And even the text colors?

[image]